# Conditional CSS styling depending on even/odd number of checkbox ticks

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to create conditional CSS styling on several `<input type="checkbox">` when the total number of checkmarks is even or odd.

This isn't part of any larger project; I have just been considering this as a thought experiment. I have created a working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/gu4ur6us/

This works as expected and displays `even` or `odd` depending on how many checkboxs are ticked. The issue is that there are **160** `:checked` and `:not(:checked)` selectors for *5* checkboxs! Is there a better way?

Comment: The obvious answer would probably be "just use JavaScript and use `.classList.add`/`.classList.remove` based on a simple count"?

Comment: You could probably do it with [`nth-of-type`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/)

Comment: @MichaelElliott `:checked` does not change `type`. Type is still `input`, regardless of how many preceding siblings are (un)checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most frontend engineers would write a JavaScript routine to run each time a checkbox is changed, count all checked inputs and change the span contents based on the count.

However, if that's not an option, here's a shorter form of your CSS:

```css
span:after, 
:checked~:checked~span:after, 
:checked~:checked~:checked~:checked~span:after {
  content: 'even';
}

:checked~span:after,
:checked~:checked~:checked~span:after, 
:checked~:checked~:checked~:checked~:checked~span:after {
  content: 'odd';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">

<span></span>
```

If you want to limit it to a particular case, just wrap them in a parent with a short, specific, class and prefix each selector with that parent selector + a space.

Also, if JavaScript is not an option, you could look into SCSS to write a function that would take a few useful params (i.e.: number of checkboxes, parent) and would output all the necessary CSS (the above code would be the output for 5 checkboxes).

I tried my hand at it. Could probably be simplified, but here's a rough version:

https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/g0dpgvfp/

```css
// =============================================== variables. change as needed.
$times: 21;
$selector: ':checked~';
$prefix:'';     // parent selector (prefix), if needed
$sufix: 'span:after';

// =============================================== functions.
@function make-selector($times, $selector, $prefix, $sufix) {
  $output: '';
  @for $i from 1 through $times {
      $output:#{$output}#{$selector};
  }
  @return #{$prefix}#{$output}#{$sufix}
}
@function two-by-two($times, $selector, $prefix, $sufix, $even) {
  $output: '';
  $i: 0;
  @while $i*2 < $times*2 - 1 {
    $output:#{$output}#{make-selector($i+$even, $selector, $prefix, $sufix)};
    @if $i*2 < $times*2 - 3 {
      $output:#{$output}#{','};
    }
    $i:$i+2;
  }
  @return $output;
}

// =============================================== output.
#{$prefix}#{$sufix},
#{two-by-two($times,$selector,$prefix,$sufix,0)} {
  content: 'even';
}
#{two-by-two($times,$selector,$prefix,$sufix,1)} {
  content: 'odd';
}
```

The JavaScript version is, more or less, a one liner and would have taken 2 minutes to develop. Also, it's a lot more elegant, if you ask me.

What I wrote above might impress a freshmen, but it's a huge loss of development time when compared to the js version (unless there is a specific requirement not to use JavaScript - which everyone, including governments, banks, payment portals, embraces today). Also, note the above lacks flexibility in terms of markup structure (all checkboxes need to be siblings), whereas with JavaScript we could easily count checkboxes from all over the page, as one would expect in a real scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Guess we're talking about a pure CSS challenge just for the lols (as counting with javascript and switching classes would be what we would choose for an actual project), so here we go...

A slightly less overloaded (but still ridiculously specific approach) would be to have increasingly repeating css siblings selectors, up to your max number of checkboxes.

something like

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span{ background:red }

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span{ background:green }

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span{ background:red }
```

and so on.

https://jsfiddle.net/gu4ur6us/23/

still far from a decent approach :p Will see if I can get to a better solution